# I need to host site in IIS for Https protocol with IP address only rather then HostName

Tags: .net, ssl, iis, hosting

I have one application in .net which i want to host on server which can access **through IP(Not by Host name) only in HTTPS protocol**. I have Self sign certificate if i am doing it with host name then its working.

But As per Requirement i have to do it with IP only due to some security reasons. Is this possible to do? If yes then how can I do it?

I have created application Pool, Site, SSL Certificate. If I am hosting it with only in Http mode then also its working but when I changed it to https it not working.

Comment: What is not working? What does the certificate look like?

Comment: Its just Simple self signed certificate nothing magic there which I generated. when I am trying to access my url with https its give error like Your connection is not secure

Comment: It is giving you this error because cert is self-signed

Comment: So If I will have Domain SSL Certificate then it will going to work?